# jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout() is not working

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I want to throw timeout exception , If my query takes more than 10 secs to execute .

I am using Hikari datasource properties and spring jdbc template. I executed the same update statement without commit, in oracle client to bring the deadlock scenario . My code keeps waiting to execute not throwing timeout exception.

```
@Bean 
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(HikariDataSource ds) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(10);
    return jdbcTemplate;

}

public class DaoImpl {

   @Autowired
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
   methodToUpdateQuery() {
      jdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery);
   }
}
```